# How to insert a custom code between the posts inside the Wordpress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now I have a very basic Wordpress loop:

```
<?php 

// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'    => 30,
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));

if( $posts ): ?>

<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
        
setup_postdata( $post )
        
        ?>
        
    
<?php the_title(); ?>
    

<?php endforeach; ?>
    
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically I'm trying to insert an ad between the posts.

And have an option to specify after how many posts the ad code would appear.

So if I type 3, then it would look like this:

```
Post 1 title

Post 2 title

Post 3 title

AD

Post 4 title

Post 5 title

Post 6 title

AD

...
```

In the other similar thread I have found that I can do that using a counter:

`$i = 1;`

```
if($i==3||$i==5||$i==10){
            /*Adsence here*/
            }
```

`$i++;`

But I have no idea how to implement that into my code.

Not a coder, just trying to combine something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a counter, set it to zero and add one to it after every loop. You can then check for the current value of the counter and do things when it reaches a certain value.

```
<?php 

// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'    => 30,
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));

$counter = 0;

if( $posts ): ?>

<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
        
setup_postdata( $post )     
?>
          
<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php 
// checks if $counter exists in the array
if (in_array($counter, array(3, 6, 9))) {
    // do something when $counter is equal to 3, 6, or 9
    // such as rendering an ad
}

$counter++;
?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
    
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks to both for a help! iismaell's answer was closest to my code and was easy to implement. that's why I accepted it as an answer. Appreciate it for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could set this up in multiple ways. For example you could use `current_post` inside the loop to get the current loop index:

```php
$posts = new wp_query(
  array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'    => 30,
    'order'             => 'DESC'
  )
);

if( $posts ):

  while($posts->have_posts())
  {

    $posts->the_post();

    $current_post = $posts->current_post; // starts from zero

    if($current_post == 2 || $current_post == 4 || $current_post == 9):?>

      <div>YOUR ADSENCE</div>

    <?php

    endif;

    ?>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

  <?php 
  }

endif;
```

Or if you want to use a `counter`, then you could do something like this:

```php
$posts = new wp_query(
  array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'    => 30,
    'order'             => 'DESC'
  )
);

if( $posts ):

  $i = 1; // starts from one OR you could change it to zero to starts from zero if you want to

  while($posts->have_posts())
  {

    $posts->the_post();

    if($i == 3 || $i == 5 || $i == 10):?>

      <div>YOUR ADSENCE</div>

    <?php

    endif;

    ?>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

  <?php 

  $i++;

  }

endif;
```